# Calculate a new vector `t` from vector `d` that points in the same xz direction as d, but is also perpendicular to `v`

Tags: vectors

Imagine a normalized vector `v` and a normalized vector `d` who both point in random directions. But for vector `d` the y component is always 0. Now I would like to construct a new normalized vector `t` that points in the same xz direction as `d` (points in the same direction from a birds eye view, but who also perpendicular to `v`.

I was thinking of just calculating the dot product between `v` and `d` and just setting it to 0 and solving for dy:
0=(vx*dx)+(vz*dz)+(vy*dy)

but this won't work, because then the resulting vector would not be normalized, making the result invalid.

Comment: There are typos in the Post. Eg "construct a new normalized vector t ... perpendicular to t" : How can it be Perpendicular to itself ? You want $t$ or $v$ ?

Comment: sorry i meant t is perpendicular to v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=(d_x,d_y,d_z)$ where $d_y=0$ & $d_x^2+d_y^2+d_z^2=1$ (normalized)

Let $v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ where $v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2=1$ (normalized)

Let $t=(t_x,t_y,t_z)$ where $t_x^2+t_y^2+t_z^2=1$ (normalized)

**ASSUMING** , you want $d$ to contribute $xz$ Direction to $t$ , which must be Perpendicular to $v$ , we get try to get **un-normalized** vector $t_u$ :
We get $t_u=(d_x,P,d_z)$ where $d_x v_x + P v_y + d_z v_z = 0$

With that Equation , we can easily get $P$ to then get $t_u$ which can then be normalized to get $t$.

**Naturally , $t_u$ & $t$ will have the same Directions we want , while $t_u$ will additionally be normalized.**

The Crux of the OP Doubt (given via comments) is :
"do 2 perpendicular vectors dot product really equal 0 even if they are not both lenght 1?"

Yes : Consider 2 normalized vectors A & B Perpendicular to each other, where we get :
$A_x B_x + A_y B_y + A_z B_z = 0$
Multiplying both sides by arbitrary Constants C_1 & C_2 will give :

$C_1 C_2 A_x B_x + C_1 C_2 A_y B_y + C_1 C_2 A_z B_z = C_1 C_2 0 = 0$

$C_1 A_x C_2 B_x + C_1 A_y C_2 B_y + C_1 A_z C_2 B_z = 0$

This is Equivalent to two vectors $(C_1 A)$ & $(C_2 B)$ with scaling , whose Dot Product is still $0$ (these two vectors are still Perpendicular to each other) , even though the lengths are arbitrary & not $1$.

Comment: do 2 perpendicular vectors dot product really equal 0 even if they are not both lenght 1?

Comment: I have updated my Answer to respond to your Query. @user2741831